# Add item to “New” context menu in Windows 8 for only one user without admin rights

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, batch-file

I am trying to edit the registry on my windows 8 computer so that I can create a batch(.bat) file from the "new" menu. The only problem is I don't have admin rights. So I was doing some research and found that you can edit some parts of the registry. Is there some way that I can edit the menu for just my user so I don't need admin rights? maybe would it be in "HKEY_CURRENT_USER". Also I currently have this which needs admin rights:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat]
@="batch"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bat\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batch]
@="Blank Batch file"
```

Comment: What are you asking?  You appear to want some for of superuser abilities without actually being a superuser.  Is that it?  I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Not tried, but:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a [combined view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of two registry branches:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes
```

The combined view shows the data in the local machine brach by default when there is no data (same key/value) in the current user branch, but the current user branch has precedence. So, in theory, the equivalent to your posted code should be

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat]
@="batch"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\.bat\ShellNew]
"NullFile"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\batch]
@="Blank Batch file"
```

As it is writting under the current user branch, there is no need for admin rights.